# Powershell Get-DistributionGroup ManagedBy - взять почтовые адреса

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, по командлету Get-DistributionGroup
Мне нужно вытащить владельцев групп рассылок, из группы рассылки. Т.е.

```
$gr = test_distr_gr
(Get-DistributionGroup $gr).managedby
```

Выдаются полные пути до объектов в AD. Не могу сообразить, как из этого вытащить email этих владельцев. Использую только стандартные АДшные и Эксченж командлеты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
$gr = "test_distr_gr"
(Get-DistributionGroup $gr).managedby|%{Get-Recipient $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}|select -ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress
```